# When Desrialize in json ,not all the properties come out from the file

Tags: c#, json.net

when im trying to desrialize to abstract class list,The Genres property in Book class stay Null, While in Journal class its get the value from my json file.

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
using (FileStream streamFile = File.Open($"{folderPath}//products10.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamFile))
   {
       string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
       productsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductBase>>(fileContent,ProductBase.StrandartJsonConvert);
   }
}
```

This is the JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "EditorName":"Me",
        "Name":"DailyMail",
        "IssueNumber":4,
        "Genres":[1],
        "Frequency":0,
        "Id":"01c26581-3e3a-4bc2-bc97-dfbab0215f29",
        "Description":"DailyMail",
        "PublicationDate":"2022-01-19T12:44:32.57574+02:00",
        "BasePrice":15.0,
        "Type":"Journal"
    },
    {
        "AuthorName":"Author",
        "Title":"HarryPotter",
        "Edition":3,
        "Geners":[2,1],
        "Synopsis":null,
        "Id":"6674b82d-6d6d-49ac-9c92-7d84b0dd09b6",
        "Description":"HarryPotter",
        "PublicationDate":"2022-01-19T12:44:30.2413124+02:00",
        "BasePrice":35.0,
        "Type":"Book"
    }
]
```

While in my journal class everything get in, in my book class - it isn't, it looks like the deserializtion ignores the `Genres` property.

```
public class Journal : ProductBase
{
    public string EditorName { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return base.Description; }
        set { base.Description = value; }
    }

    public int IssueNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<JournalGenre> Genres { get; set; }

    public JournalFrequency Frequency { get; set; }

    public Journal(string editorName, string name, int issueNumber, DateTime publicationDate,
        decimal basePrice, JournalFrequency frequency, params JournalGenre[] genres)
        : base(name, publicationDate, basePrice)
    {
        this.EditorName = editorName;
        this.IssueNumber = issueNumber;
        this.Frequency = frequency;
        this.Genres = genres.ToList();
    }
}
```

here all the properties get the values.

```
public class Book : ProductBase
{
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string Title 
    { 
        get { return base.Description; } 
        set { base.Description = value; } 
    }
    public int Edition { get; set; }
        
    public ICollection<BookGenre> Geners { get; set; }
        
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }

    public Book(string authorName, string title, DateTime publicationDate, decimal basePrice, int edition = 1, params BookGenre[] genres)
        :base(title, publicationDate, basePrice)
    {
        this.AuthorName = authorName;
        this.Edition = edition;
        this.Geners = genres.ToList();
    }
}
```

but here the Genres stays null - the 'genres' in the const isnt get the value from the JSON file - only this prop. anything else get value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why @JamesS deleted his answer, but he's right - the property in the JSON file is `Geners` for your `Book`, but the constructor parameter is `genres`.

Either correct the spelling of the property on the class and in the JSON file to `Genres`:

```c#
public class Book : ProductBase
{
    ...    
    public ICollection<BookGenre> Genres { get; set; }
```

```json
{
    "AuthorName":"Author",
    "Title":"HarryPotter",
    "Edition":3,
    "Genres":[2,1],
    "Synopsis":null,
    "Id":"6674b82d-6d6d-49ac-9c92-7d84b0dd09b6",
    "Description":"HarryPotter",
    "PublicationDate":"2022-01-19T12:44:30.2413124+02:00",
    "BasePrice":35.0,
    "Type":"Book"
}
```

Or change the spelling of the constructor parameter to match the name used in the JSON file:

```c#
public Book(
    string authorName, 
    string title, 
    DateTime publicationDate, 
    decimal basePrice, 
    int edition = 1, 
    params BookGenre[] geners)
```